# Send SMS via AWS SNS service using nodejs keeps getting invalid token error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am trying to send and SMS using AWS SNS using node JS code.
and I am getting

> InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is
>   invalid.

Using a parallel code accessing S3 requires no token (using the system token)
This code is planned to run in Lambda later on and embedding token in the code is not good practice.
My SNS code sample:

```
var params = {
        Message: 'Hi this is message from AWS_SNS', /* required */
        MessageAttributes: {
            someKey: {
                DataType: 'String' ,
                StringValue: 'String'
            },
        },
        MessageStructure: 'String',
        PhoneNumber: 'Some Number',
        Subject: 'MYSubject',
        //TargetArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:798298080689:SMS',
        //TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:798298080689:SendSMS'
    };
    var sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31',region:'eu-west-1'});
    sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
```

A sample how in the same project my S3 Code works with no token

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.listObjects({
  Bucket: 'some backet',
  MaxKeys: '1000'
}, next);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issues, it was clearly a wrong token :-(
From some reason my token has been revoked.